Average cost minimized when AC = MC
Let $C(x)$ be the total cost of producing $x$ units of a commodity. Then the average cost per unit is $c(x)=\frac{C(x)}{x}.$ It is trivial to show $c’(x)=0\implies$ the marginal cost $C’(x)=c(x)$ since $$c’(x)=\frac{C’(x)-\frac{C(x)}{x}}{x}=\frac{C’(x)}{x}-\frac{c(x)}{x}$$
However, the problem requires we show average cost is minimized at this critical point. How do we know there is only one solution $x$ to $C’(x) = c(x)$ and how do we know $c’(t)<0$ for $t<x$ and $c’(t)>0$ for $t>x$?
It seems we need to make an additional assumption that $C’’(x)>0$ since $$c’’(x)=\frac{xC’’(x)-C’(x)}{x^2}-\frac{xc’(x)-c(x)}{x^2}=$$ $$ =\frac{C’’(x)}{x}-\frac{C’(x)}{x^2}-\frac{c’(x)}{x} +\frac{c(x)}{x^2}=\frac{C’’(x)}{x}$$
since $C’(x) = c(x)$ and $c’(x) = 0.$
Is is true we have to make this assumption to be rigorous?

That is correct.  The model assumes that marginal costs are increasing.  This is usually justified by the idea that there are fixed costs, and marginal costs begin below average costs.  If marginal costs are never increasing the lines will never intersect.

Yes, AC=MC is just a first-order condition (necessary but not sufficient), therefore if average cost is at minimum then AC=MC, but not otherwise (counterexample: note that it also holds for maxima). If the cost function is convex (assuming second-order differentiability, this is just the second order condition you imposed) then first-order condition becomes sufficient.
